# Pair two file / Remove duplicate entries

Tags: join, hosts

I have two host file list like this:

**file1.hosts**

```
0.0.0.0 site1.com
0.0.0.0 site2.com
```

**file2.hosts**

```
0.0.0.0 site1.com
0.0.0.0 site3.com
```

Now I want one list that looks like this:

**hosts.hosts**

```
0.0.0.0 site1.com
0.0.0.0 site2.com
0.0.0.0 site3.com
```

What is the best way to get this? 
I tried it with `join` but I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sort` instead. The `-u`-Option supressed duplicates in the output:

```bash
$ sort -u file*.hosts | tee hosts.hosts
0.0.0.0 site1.com
0.0.0.0 site2.com
0.0.0.0 site3.com
```

Note that I'm using `tee` so that we get to see the output while creating the file.

You could just as well just use redirection instead:

```
$ sort -u file*.hosts > hosts.hosts
```